# Treeview node not expanding on clicking on text

Tags: treeview

I have a tree view in which there are two child nodes with `parentID 0` and a main node with no ID.

```
Root Node
0--> Child 1

0--> Child 2`
```

The problem is that whenever I click on Child 2, the Child 1 node gets expanded. I have checked using breakpoints and found out that whenever I click on Child 2, the `selectednode.text` shows Child 1. How can I clear this?

```
    `Treeview1_SelectedNodeChanged()
    {
    Datatable dt = //Treeview binding
    ds.tables.add(dt);
    TreeNode selectedNode = New TreeNode();
    selectedNode = this.Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text;
    }`
```

Here selectedNode always shows the text of the first Child node even if I click on the second Child Node. I am binding the tree from the SQL table using a datatable.

The code for tree view binding is as follows

'PageLoad()
    {
        (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.GetParentNodes();
        }
    }

```
public void GetParentNodes()
{
    try
    {
        TreeNode topNode = New TreeNode();
        topNode.Text = "Reference Document";
        topNode.Value = "0";
        topNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand();
        topNode.CollapseAll();
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(topNode);
        DataTable dt = obj.SelectDocument("DocumentId");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ds.Relations.Add("ChildRow",ds.Tables[0]Columns["Id"],ds.Tables[0]Columns["ParentId"],false);
        foreach(DataRow firstDataRows in ds.Tables[0]Rows)
        {
            if(Convert.toInt32(firstDataRows["ParentId"] == 0)
            {
                TreeNode parentTreeNode = New TreeNode();
                parentTreeNode.Text = firstDataRows["FolderName"].ToString();
                parentTreeNode.Value = firstDataRows["ParentId"].ToString();
                parentTreeNode.SelectAction =                                         TreeNodeSelection.SelectExpand();
                parentTreeNode.CollapseAll();
                parentTreeNode.Selected = True;
                topNode.ChildNodes.Add(parentTreeNode);
                GetChildNodes(firstDataRows,parentTreeNode);
            }'
```

Thank & Regards,
SaJ

Comment: Please specify your coding environment

Comment: The script is done in C# for an ASP.Net Website. The tree works fine when clicked on the + sign, but on clicking the node text it doesn't work. I have used the below code


Treeview1_SelectedNodeChanged()
{
Datatable dt = //Treeview binding
ds.tables.add(dt);
TreeNode selectedNode = New TreeNode();
selectedNode = this.Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text;
}

Here selectedNode always shows the text of the first Child node even if I click on the second Child Node. I am binding the tree from the SQL table using a datatable.

Thanks & Regards,
SaJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem is solved by making a small change as mentioned below...

By Changing

```js
parentTreeNode.Value = firstDataRows["ParentId"].ToString();

to 

parentTreeNode.Value = firstDataRows["Id"].ToString();
```

Thanks & Regards,
Sajin A